# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when init a struct

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm developing an app in Objective-C/OSX (first try). I had a struct (NSDevice custom type) which need to be accessed as a public/extern variable to allow the different interface of the class to access it.

Here is the declaration in the header.

```
struct NSDevice{
    LIBMTP_raw_device_t * usbrawdevice;
    int numusbrawdevice;
    uint32_t rawdeviceID;

    LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *device;
};

extern struct NSDevice *Device;

@interface DeviceManager : NSObject

- (void) openDevice;
- (void) closeDevice;

@end
```

and how I implement it in the source file

```
#import "DeviceManager.h"

struct NSDevice *Device = NULL;


@implementation DeviceManager



- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        NSLog(@"Init");
        LIBMTP_Init();

        Device->device = NULL;
        Device->numusbrawdevice = 0;
        Device->rawdeviceID = 0;
        Device->usbrawdevice = NULL;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMtp_error) openDevice {
    LIBMTP_error_number_t error = LIBMTP_ERROR_GENERAL;

    NSLog(@"Opening Device");

    error = LIBMTP_Detect_Raw_Devices(&Device->usbrawdevice, &Device->numusbrawdevice);
```

When trying to init the struct in the init interface, I got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any idea ?

Can I use the "struct" or is there a better way in Objective-C ?

Thx

Comment: You declare a pointer called `* Device` but I don't see anywhere that you create a struct for it to point at.

Comment: Sorry bad copy paste...

Comment: I'm still not seeing any `Device = ...` kind of logic.

Comment: @Philip... I should be tired but not catch the point. Device is init at top of the source file when doing struct NSDevice *Device = NULL;

Comment: Exactly.  It's NULL, which means it's not pointing to an actual, initialized struct.  So when you say `Device->device = NULL;`, it's effectively like typing NULL->device = NULL;.

Comment: Cocoa uses two-letter prefixes for pseudo-namespacing. The `NS` prefix is reserved for stuff written by Apple; **never** use it for your own types.

Comment: @Josh. Thx I already remove them

Answer (score 0):

Seb, you need to allocate the space for `Device`.

Try doing this:

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        NSLog(@"Init");
        LIBMTP_Init();

        Device = malloc(sizeof(NSDevice));
        Device->device = NULL;
        Device->numusbrawdevice = 0;
        Device->rawdeviceID = 0;
        Device->usbrawdevice = NULL;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and declare your structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
    LIBMTP_raw_device_t * usbrawdevice;
    int numusbrawdevice;
    uint32_t rawdeviceID;

    LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *device;
} NSDevice;
```

Also, I ***highly recommend*** changing the name of `NSDevice` to `SebDevice` or something that doesn't start with `NS` as those prefix characters usually signify something built into the MacOS SDK and it's going to confuse anyone else who has to look at your code after you depart the project.

And one last thing, global variables like this shouldn't start with capital letters.  In Objective-C, best practice is for variables to start with lower case letters or maybe a `g` (for global) or an underscore.  Change `Device` to `gDevice`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried before but it complain in NSDevice. The struct is declared in the header but the malloc is not able to resolve the symbol NSDevice

Comment: You need to add a "`typedef`" in front of the structure declaration.

Comment: Thanks but compiler complain on Device->device = NULL; by saying it's incomplete definition

Comment: Did you include the `.h` files that define what `LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t` is?  Also, what happens when you change `NULL` to `nil`?

Comment: No change and include was here.

Comment: struct sDevice *gDevice = nil;
is added before the @implementation in src and also in the header declared : extern struct sDevice *gDevice;

Comment: Sure sounds like the definition of `LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t` isn't found (or included in the right place).  Can you temporarily delete the declaration of `Device` and try declaring `LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *device` in your `init` method and see if you can set it to `NULL`?

Comment: it works. there is no complain.. LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t *device can be initialised to null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84213/discussion-between-seb-and-michael-dautermann).